# Implement jquery like functions addClass, removeClass and delay in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, queue, promise

Assume $ is not the browser. Now have to implement $, it will take a string, which is a query, it will use the querySelector to select the element. (Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

```
$('text')
```

Now implement jquery like functions addClass and removeClass. (Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

```
$('#test').removeClass('blue').addClass('red');
```

Now implement jquery like functions delay. (Reference: https://api.jquery.com/delay/)

```
$('#test').removeClass('blue').delay(2000).delay(1000).addClass('red');
```

Code Sample

```js
function $(selector) {
    let element = document.querySelector(selector)
    element.queue = []
    element.active = false
    return element
}

Element.prototype.next = function () {
    if (this.queue.length) this.runTask(this.queue.shift())
}

Element.prototype.runTask = function (callBack) {
    this.active = true
    callBack().then(() => {
        this.active = false
        this.next()
    })
}

Element.prototype.register = function(callBack){
    if (this.active) {
        this.queue.push(callBack)
    } else {
        this.runTask(callBack)
    }
}

Element.prototype.addClass = function (className) {
    that = this
    let callBack = () => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(function () {
        that.classList.add(className)
        resolve()
    }, 0))
    this.register(callBack)
    return this
}

Element.prototype.removeClass = function (className) {
    that = this
    let callBack = () => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(function () {
        that.classList.remove(className)
        resolve()
    }, 0))
    this.register(callBack)
    return this
}

Element.prototype.delay = function (ms) {
    that = this
    let callBack = () => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(function () {
        resolve()
    }, ms))

    this.register(callBack)
    return this
}

$('#test')
.removeClass("red").delay(500)
.addClass("blue").delay(500).delay(500).removeClass("blue")
.delay(500).addClass("red").delay(500).removeClass("red")
.delay(500).addClass("blue").delay(500).removeClass("blue")
.delay(500).addClass("red").delay(500).removeClass("red")
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .blue{
                background-color: blue;
            }
            .red{
                background-color: red;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="test" style="width: 150px; height: 150px; margin:10px;" class="red"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Can anyone please review the Code?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. Does the code work successfully? Can you tell us more about what the code is supposed to do? References are good for bonus context, but the problem you solved should be clearly stated in the question itself. Thank you.

Comment: Does it boil down to writing an alternative for `addClass`, `removeClass` and `delay`? Any limitations on this? What prompted you to do this? How does this differ from something like `text.classList.add("foo")`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mutating built-in prototypes is not a good idea. It's not only inelegant, it can also lead to conflicts when other scripts on the page expect the prototypes to be unmutated. (It can even [damage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55934491) future attempts to integrate functionality officially, if enough sites use the bad code.)

Instead of using `Element.prototype`, create your own class, and put methods onto *its* prototype.

If you want to emulate jQuery, you should probably select *all* elements that match the selector, not just the first one. (Using a collection of elements will also avoid errors if the collection is empty - jQuery doesn't error when methods are called on an empty collection)

The `active` flag would be more informative if it was named more precisely, perhaps call it `methodInProgress`.

`that = this` [is an antipattern](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#naming--self-this) in modern Javascript. If you need to use the calling context from the outer scope, use arrow functions instead. (You're already using ES2015 in multiple places)

`callback` is a single word, not two, so the proper way to camelCase it would be to keep it as-is. Calling the arguments `callBack` instead could result in bugs later when other readers/writers of the code expect it to be formatted conventionally.

Promises should be reserved for *asynchronous* actions. If you're going to run something that's completely synchronous, using a Promise adds unnecessary and confusing noise. Consider having your functions return Promises *only if they're asynchronous*, and while processing the queue, if a callback returns a Promise, wait for the Promise to resolve before moving onto the next callback. If the callback *doesn't* return a Promise, you can still `await` it without errors, and the next queue callback will run immediately.

Since you have multiple methods which add callback to the queue and `return this`, consider passing those methods through a helper function to make the code a bit more DRY.

Refactored:

```js
const $ = selector => new PsuedoJquery(selector);
class PsuedoJquery {
  constructor(selector) {
    this.elements = [...document.querySelectorAll(selector)];
    this.queue = [];
  }
  async runNext() {
    await this.queue.shift()();
    if (this.queue.length) {
      await this.runNext();
    } else {
      this.methodInProgress = false;
    }
  }
  register(callback) {
    this.queue.push(callback);
    // If errors are a possibility, catch them here
    if (!this.methodInProgress) {
      this.methodInProgress = true;
      this.runNext();
    }
  }
  makeChainable(callback) {
    this.register(callback);
    return this;
  }
  addClass(className) {
    return this.makeChainable(() => {
      for (const elm of this.elements) {
        elm.classList.add(className);
      }
    });
  }
  removeClass(className) {
    return this.makeChainable(() => {
      for (const elm of this.elements) {
        elm.classList.remove(className);
      }
    });
  }
  delay(ms) {
    return this.makeChainable(() => new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(resolve, ms);
    }));
  }
}

$('#test')
  .removeClass("red").delay(500)
  .addClass("blue").delay(500).delay(500).removeClass("blue")
  .delay(500).addClass("red").delay(500).removeClass("red")
  .delay(500).addClass("blue").delay(500).removeClass("blue")
  .delay(500).addClass("red").delay(500).removeClass("red")
```

```css
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="test" style="width: 150px; height: 150px; margin:10px;" class="red"></div>
```